# Resolving message "Loading jwk to TPM2 failed!"

Tags: centos, tpm

I'm at my wits' end on this one. A CentOS 7 box with a TPM module.

If I reboot it from the terminal, it seems fine. But if I hard reboot it, it apparently gets stuck in this state, spitting out:

`Nov 13 15:17:44 dracut-initqueue: Loading jwk to TPM2 failed!`

For **two hours**, before spitting out:

```
systemd-cryptsetup: Set cipher aes, mode xts-plain64, key size 512 bits for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx.
Nov 13 15:17:52 kernel: alg: No test for fips(ansi_cprng) (fips_ansi_cprng)
Nov 13 15:17:53 systemd: Found device /dev/mapper/luks-xxx.
Nov 13 15:17:53 systemd: Started Cryptography Setup for luks-xxx.
Nov 13 15:17:53 systemd: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
Nov 13 15:17:53 systemd: Reached target System Initialization.
Nov 13 15:17:53 systemd: Reached target Basic System.
```

And then finally loading the OS.

I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful as an introduction of what is (probably) going on:
https://blog.dowhile0.org/2017/10/18/automatic-luks-volumes-unlocking-using-a-tpm2-chip/

Based on the messages, your system has a LUKS disk encryption configured, apparently using the TPM module as a key store. The messages after the **two hours'** wait look like normal diagnostic messages from activating an encrypted root filesystem.

The infrastructure between LUKS and the TPM tools may be provided by the `clevis` package, and that `Loading jwk to TPM2 failed!` sure looks like a message from `clevis`.

With quick googling, I found this: https://github.com/latchset/clevis/issues/95

Apparently there is/used to be some kind of an issue that would trigger the rate-limiting feature of the TPM. That makes me think a workaround might be to apply some sort of a delay or a check that the TPM module is fully ready, before initiating the TPM procedures for retrieving/decrypting the disk encryption unlock key.

This might not qualify as a complete Answer, but I hope it at least helps you to understand what might be happening and perhaps give you ideas for further diagnostics.